# 64 bit SQL Server 2012 is not visible for other sytems on the network

Tags: sql-server, connectivity

I have brand new SQL Server 2012 installed on 64 bit windows 7 Pro system.

I wonder how I can make this SQL Server visible for the rest of the network?

Right now when I attempt to find it via SQL Server Management Studio on for example windows 2003 server - it just not there.

And I can not connect to it via ODBC either because that new SQL Server not no the list of available database engines on my network.

I can see shared files over windows explorer, so nothing wrong with Windows. And from new SQL Server Management Studio on Windows 7 I can connect to any of my existing SQL Server engines. We are running mix of 64 and 32 bit systems on the network.

What else should I do to make it work?

This is additional info: I have 32 bit application mix of legacy Classic ASP, VB6 and NET. My task is to start upgrading databases to most recent from 2005 and 2008 to 2012 edition.

Comment: Are you able to log in using SSMS when you are on the server it self? When connecting from different server what error message do you get? Are you connecting using IP or ServerName\InstanceName

Comment: When connecting from remote SSMS I am getting :server does not exists or network configuration prevent connection. But I can logon and connect to local SQL or any other system (existing SQL engine) from new SQL installation of Management Studio 2012 on the network without any problem at all.

Comment: 1. You need to check to make sure that TCP/IP is enabled, 2. Check Windows Firewall is not blocking the ports. To do first:open SQL Server configuration manager->expand Sql Server Network Configuration-> verfy that TCP/IP is not Disabled. Here is link on configuring firewall http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175043.aspx

Comment: Have you started the SQL Browser service?

Comment: Done, ports are opened and Yes to all both SaUce and SchmitzIT. Thanks guys.Still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is a solution which I found bizarre at least.

as I mentioned in my original post our network is a mix of 32 and 64-bit OS running on the same network.

I could not see the SQL 2012 server (64 bit OS) until I shut down the firewall on the Server OS. Just opening ports on Server side did not do a thing to improve situation. Is this a bug on OS or a firewall? - I do not know.

So currently I am using AV firewall capability on the server as well as general network firewalls but not windows firewall on the server.

Thanks all of you who tried to help.

Answer (score 8):

@SaUce comment above is right on.  To add more detail, check in the SQL Server Configuration Manager.

- Expand SQL Server Network Configuration.  Open TCP/IP.  Go to IP Addresses tab.  Scroll to bottom.  Change TCP Dynamic Ports to nothing (blank) and change TCP Port to 1433
- Ensure Windows Firewall is not blocking port 1433.  [Open a port in Windows 7 Firewall](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/open-port-windows-firewall#1TC=windows-7)
- Open Windows services and make sure the SQL Browser service is enabled and running. [Start a service](http://www.wikihow.com/Start-Services-in-Windows)

Comment: 1. TCP/IP enabled was first thing I checked.2. Port on Windows Firewall ws open this was done right after installation of SQL Server 2012. 3. SQL Browser services set to automatic and up and running.

Comment: Attempt to connect to that SQL Server 2012 via ODBC failed as well. Message: SQLState:'08001' SQL Server error:6 TCP\IP Socet: Specified SQL server does not exists. Meanwhile I can ping that computer from any machine on the network and shared drives are available.

Comment: Ok, here is a solution which I found bazaar at least.

as I meantioned in my original post our network is a mix of 32 and 64 bit OS running on the same network. I could not see SQL 2012 (64 bit OS) until I shut down firewall on the Server OS. Just opening ports on Server side did not do a thing to improve situation. Is this a bug on OS or a firewall - I do not know.

So currently I am using AV firewall capability on the server as well as general network firewalls but not windows firewall on the server.
Since I can not post my own answers or even comments...
Thank you all who try to help.

Comment: @MTAdmin this solution works for me perfect!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Installing the SQL Server Management studio alone will not help it. We need to install the SQL Express As well from below link [microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299) and the Instance will now start showing in the Local Server list. –